# jQuery append() not working for concatenated String

Tags: jquery, html, append, string-concatenation

(Full code below)

This

```
$('#' + id).parent().append('<div id="pop-up">hello</div>');
```

does work. But this

```
$('#' + id).parent().append('<div id="pop-up-' + id + '">hello</div>');
```

doesn't.

The fact that the first version works lets me assume that the problem is not the `id` variable...

So the full code is

```
function clickOnElement(id) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.clicked = String(id);
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../db/RequestHandler.ashx',
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset-utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            // Add the div for the dialog-box
            $('<div>Hello</div>', {
                "id": "pop-up" + id
            }).appendTo($('#' + id).parent());
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("request error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `.append` expects an element and not string. If you have HTML string, use `.html()` instead

Comment: `.append()` will work after the DOM load.
parent div is loaded but concurrently you are appending to that element which is not in DOM at that time.
try to append after the document ready

Comment: works perfeclty fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/gx6mrqr7/

Comment: where is the id coming from?

Comment: I am developing in ASP.NET Razor: `$('#@r.id').click(function() {
                clickOnElement(@r.id);
            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
var parent = $('#' + id).parent();
var el = $('<div>', {id: "pop-up"+id,text:"hello"});
 el.appendTo(parent);
```

the proper way to add text to a created object is to use the text property:

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/gx6mrqr7/

Comment: This actually worked. Thank you. Any suggestions why?

Comment: from what i can tell jquery can't add property to a closed div `<div>Hello</div>`

Comment: I also noticed that `"pop-up-" + id` doesn't work, but `"pop-up" + id` does.

Comment: Well, I'm not relying on the `-` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use **[.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)**

- The `.append()` and `.appendTo()` methods perform the same task.
- The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target.
- With .append(), the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted.
- With .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container.

**Code Example**

```
$('<div>Hello</div>', {
    "id": "pop-up" + id
}).appendTo($('#' + id).parent());
```

FYI,

Please make sure the element exists in the DOM and you're appending it in correct selector.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you made a mistake with the `'` but I corrected it. This `$('#' + id).parent().append("<div id='pop-up" + id + "'>hello</div>");` seems to work. Can anyone explain why??

Comment: I've updated my answer, just make sure that your use `appendTo` at right one.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with `.append()` it's just a quotation mark confilct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `div` is appended correctly now. Only the `id` attribute is not working yet. But maybe I could do a workaround with the `.attr()` method of jQuery.

Comment: Okay, Glad to see that it finally helps you.

Comment: Yes, but it's not solved yet ;-) `div` Element is shown but still no `id` attrbiute...

Comment: Can you show me full code to check the exact problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Create HTML using [jQuery(html, attributes)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes), You will be safe from quotes mess

```
$('#' + id)
    .parent()
    .append($('<div>', {
        id: "pop-up-" + id ,
        text: "hello"
    });
```